# How does Martial Cadence (Jarvan IV) work?

Tags: league-of-legends

Who can explain me the Marcial Cadence (Innate) ability of new champion, Jarvan IV?

> Jarvan IV's first attack on a target deals 6/8/10% of their current
>   Health as bonus physical damage (max: 400 damage). This effect cannot
>   occur on the same target for 6 seconds. (Levels up at levels 1/7/13)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Essentially, when you deal autoattack damage to a champion, you deal an additional 8% of their current HP as physical damage.

So if an enemy champion has 1000 HP, you will deal (ATK) + (1000 * .08 ) physical damage to that champion (reduced by armor, normally). This effect wont occur on the same target quicker than once every 6 seconds, BUT you can rapidly switch targets with your autoattack and get that benefit on them over and over again, since it's a cooldown based per target, and not Jarvan himself.

Comment: It *is* physical damage, though, so it will get reduced by Armor appropriately.

Comment: @Raven Correct. The extra damage is not true damage. It simply means that when Jarvan attacks and this procs, he has a multi-component attack against his target, with part on the physical DR check, and the other on the magical.

Comment: What's the difference between attacking and auto-attacking? Does it apply only on auto-attack?

Comment: @Drake As far as I know, it only applies on his auto-attack (right click). I don't believe this applies to his abilities, based on what I've seen in videos and read by the Riot staff.

Comment: @Drake auto-attack is what you do when you right-click or press a then click. "attacking" is meaningless in this context, as there are only two real offensive options -- auto-attack or abilities.